# Javascript animation goes wrong when tab is inactive

Tags: javascript, animation, setinterval, requestanimationframe, gsap

Sample:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgZMVd/

html file:

```
<div class="game-page">
</div>
```

css file:

```
.game-page {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: grey;
}

.stick {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -94px;
    top: -60px;
    width: 188px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  init();
});

var CSS_CLASS = { STICK: "stick" },
    changeSpeedTime = 1000, //in milliseconds
    gameTime = 60, //in seconds
    timer = 1, //in seconds
    windowWidth = 1024,
    windowHeight = 768,
    stickTop = -60,
    restStickTime = 0, //in milliseconds
    initialStickInterval = 1000, //in milliseconds
    stickInterval = null, //in milliseconds
    initialStickDuration = 7, //in seconds
    stickDuration = null, //in seconds
    stickTweensArray = [],
    changeSpeedInterval = null,
    countdownTimerInterval = null,
    generateSticksInterval = null,
    generateSticksTimeout = null,
    $gamePage = null;

function init() {
  initVariables();
  initGamePage();
}

function changingSpeedFunction(x){
  var y = Math.pow(2, (x / 20));
  return y;
}

function initVariables() {
  $gamePage = $(".game-page");
  stickDuration = initialStickDuration;
  stickInterval = initialStickInterval;
}

function initGamePage() {
  TweenMax.ticker.useRAF(false);
  TweenMax.lagSmoothing(0);
  initGamePageAnimation();
}

function initGamePageAnimation () {
  generateSticks();

  changeSpeedInterval = setInterval(function () {
    changeSpeed();
  }, changeSpeedTime);

  countdownTimerInterval = setInterval(function () {
    updateCountdown();
  }, 1000);
}

function changeSpeed () {
  var x = timer;
  var y = changingSpeedFunction(x);  //change speed function
  stickDuration = initialStickDuration / y;
  stickInterval = initialStickInterval / y;

  changeCurrentSticksSpeed();
  generateSticks();
}

function changeCurrentSticksSpeed () {
  stickTweensArray.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    var tween = item.tween;
    var $stick = item.$stick;

    var oldTime = tween._time;
    var oldDuration = tween._duration;
    var newDuration = stickDuration;
    var oldPosition = stickTop;
    var newPosition = $stick.position().top;
    var oldStartTime = tween._startTime;

    var distance = newPosition - oldPosition;
    var oldSpeed = distance / oldTime;
    var newSpeed = oldSpeed * oldDuration / newDuration;
    var newTime = distance / newSpeed;
    var currentTime = oldStartTime + oldTime;
    var newStartTime = currentTime - newTime;

    item.tween._duration = newDuration;
    item.tween._startTime = newStartTime;
  });
}

function generateSticks () {
  if (restStickTime >= changeSpeedTime) {
    restStickTime -= changeSpeedTime;
    restStickTime = Math.abs(restStickTime);
  } else {
    generateSticksTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
      generateSticksInterval = setInterval(function () {
        generateStick();
        restStickTime -= stickInterval;
        if (restStickTime <= 0) {
          clearInterval(generateSticksInterval);
          restStickTime = Math.abs(restStickTime);
        }
      }, stickInterval);
      generateStick();
      restStickTime = changeSpeedTime - Math.abs(restStickTime) - stickInterval;
      if (restStickTime <= 0) {
        clearInterval(generateSticksInterval);
        restStickTime = Math.abs(restStickTime);
      }
    }, restStickTime);
  }
}

function generateStick () {
  var $stick = $("<div class='" + CSS_CLASS.STICK + "'></div>").appendTo($gamePage);

  animateStick($stick);
}

function animateStick ($stick) {
  var translateYValue = windowHeight + -stickTop;

  var tween = new TweenMax($stick, stickDuration, {
    y: translateYValue, ease: Power0.easeNone, onComplete: function () {
      $stick.remove();
      stickTweensArray.shift();
    }
  });

  stickTweensArray.push({tween:tween, $stick:$stick});
}

function updateCountdown () {
  timer++;

  if (timer >= gameTime) {
    onGameEnd();
    clearInterval(changeSpeedInterval);
    clearInterval(countdownTimerInterval);
    clearInterval(generateSticksInterval);
    clearTimeout(generateSticksTimeout);
  }
}

function onGameEnd () {
  var $sticks = $gamePage.find(".stick");
  TweenMax.killTweensOf($sticks);
}
```

So, as I researched, I have next situation:

1. TweenMax (as it uses requestAnimationFrame) freezes when tab is inactive.
2. setInterval keep going when tab is inactive (also it's delay may change when tab is inactive, depends on browser)
3. Is there any other javascript functionality that changes when tab is inactive?

Then I have 2 solutions:

1. Freeze whole game, when tab is inactive.
2. Keep going, when tab is inactive.

With first solution I have next problem: as TweenMax uses requestAnimationFrame, it works correct according to this solution (freezes animation), but how can I freeze intervals and timeouts when tab is inactive and then resume intervals and timeouts?

With second solution I can use TweenMax.lagSmoothing(0) and TweenMax.ticker.useRAF(false) for animation and it works, but anyway something goes wrong with intervals and/or timeouts. I expected that animation goes wrong because of change of interval delay to 1000+ ms when tab is inactive (according to http://stackoverflow...w-is-not-active), but I disabled acceleration and set delays to 2000ms and it didn't help.

Please help me with at least one solution. Better with both to have some variety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved problem with first solution: freeze whole game. Just used TweenMax.delayedCall() function instead of setTimeout and setInterval and whole animation synchronized pretty well.